# Can Tabs also serve as Page Titles?

Tags: tabs, header, semantics

I have a full page where there are several Tabs across the top.

The content type is a data table in the example but could be *anything*.

**Question**: Is there a need for an explicit Title if the Tab already describes what the Page is?  I understand perhaps semantically it makes sense but from a UX perspective, is it repetitive?

Note: The name of the page is already called out in the Tab. Also the style for the Selected Tab calls it out as the current page.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5hNTz.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Tabs placed at the very top of the page won't be very visible. They work best when they are in the upper middle of the page and belong to *something*.

That something is your page title. It basically defines what the page is about, and then using tabs you can categorise the information on that page.

Comment: The tabs are not used to categorize, they work as navigation to sub-pages whose Titles are the exact same as in the Tabs. The pages are very simple with single word titles that also happen to fit into the Tab.

Comment: To me, tabulated content appears to be a related set of information. In your case where information is not related, the tabs are just navigation links and you shouldn't need a title in addition to them.